# Lightning: How to detect Salesforce1 context?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Are there any way to detect that user opens lightning component within Salesforce1 or within separate app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some events are handled specifically within Salesforce1, so you can use that to check context. [See this link for a list of Salesforce1 events.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one.htm)

This example displays a toast message in Salesforce1 but not in a standalone/separate app.

```
var toast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
if (toast){
    toast.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "message": " Your contacts have been loaded successfully."
    });
    toast.fire();
} else {
        console.log("not in Salesforce1");
    }
```

Update - April 9, 2015
I was advised by an S1 developer that you can also use `$A.getContext().getApp()` to get context.

```
if (context=="one:one") {
            //you're running Salesforce1
        }
        else {
            //you're running a standalone app
        }
```

See the JavaScript API docs (https://[your-salesforce-instance]/auradocs/reference.app#reference?topic=api:Aura) for more details.

Comment: Looks like they updated this to context=="native:bridge"  worry that this is not best practice although does appear to work on ios / android..

Comment: In 2017 I don't see `getContext()` or `getApp()` methods in `$A` documentation... any updated solution?

Answer (score 1):

I Know its old question
but might be help full for other users 
as of new release, there is support by salesforce to find the context

```
 const device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor"); // DESKTOP,PHONE
```

Returns Desktop or Phone

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_browser_value_provider.htm