# Any way to detect that "e.force:showToast" will not be presented?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, toast

In the Developer Console Preview the "e.force:showToast" event is available but when fired does not produce any output. (Putting the same components in an App Builder app does produce output.)

Is there a reliable way to detect this situation? I'm indirecting through a component that could present the error inline in the page if it knew that the toast was going to fail.

(This [Lightning: How to detect Salesforce1 context?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71425/lightning-how-to-detect-salesforce1-context) isn't a solution as I *can* get a reference to the event but firing the event results in no output.)

Comment: Is this still an open question?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, Not something I care about any more, but also not solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
setErrorMessage : function(cmp, msg) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
         if(toastEvent == undefined){
            var msgDiv = cmp.find("errorMessageDiv");
            cmp.set("v.errorMessage", msg);
         }else{
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Error",
              "message": msg,
              "type": "error"
            }); 
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
    },
```

Alternatively, you can register your event in component markup and then catch it in cases where you use Lightning out in Visualforce, etc. Registering event will not return undefined from $A.get().

This is useful for system events like `navigateToComponent`

```
  <aura:registerEvent name="force:navigateToComponent" type="force:navigateToComponent" />
```

This will return event, it will fire and you can code your custom logic around, for example in your Visualforce page:

```
function navigateToVisualforce(e) {
      var params = e.getParams();
      if (params.componentDef === 'NameSpace:Foo') {
        window.parent.location.href = '/apex/baz'
      } 
    }
    $Lightning.use("NameSpace:LightningOutApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent("NameSpace:MyComponent", {}, "lightning", function (cmp) {
        // Listen to redirect events.
        $A.eventService.addHandler(
          {"event": "force:navigateToComponent", "handler": navigateToVisualforce}
        );
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to automatically identify "cases where you use Lightning out in Visualforce" which appears to include "Preview" from the Developer Console where the toast event is not undefined.

Comment: Oooh  I see what you mean, sorry!